# Pandas usage of df.index.name and df.columns.name

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say there is a Panadas DataFrame that contains movie rating data.

1) Is there a way to assign `user_id` and `movie_id` with one liner?

2) Other than visual help, is there a benefit/usage of `name` property? For example, accessing index by `user_id` etc..?

```
import pandas as pd

ratings = pd.DataFrame({0: [3, 1, 5], 1: [2, 2, 4]})
ratings.index.name = 'user_id'
ratings.columns.name = 'movie_id'
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What does "assign user_id and movie_id with one liner" mean? How are your 2 questions connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `rename_axis`

```
ratings=ratings.rename_axis('movie_id',axis=1).rename_axis('user_id',axis=0)
ratings
Out[53]: 
movie_id  0  1
user_id       
0         3  2
1         1  2
2         5  4
```

For your second question

```
ratings.eval('user_id')
Out[59]: 
user_id
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

also when you do with groupby index, you can using index name rather than `groupby(level=0)`

Comment: But if you do it inplace, you can't chain.. and then you have two lines again :)

Comment: @miradulo maybe adding `ratings=` here ?

Comment: I guess? Makes a lot of sense to do it in place though. OP's way looks  better to me.

Comment: Wen / miradulo, if either of you understand the question, could you please edit it accordingly? Can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: @jpp "One-linerize" my two lines (that are perfectly fine IMHO), and also what is the purpose of naming the index or columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your one-liner:

```
ratings.index.name, ratings.columns.name = 'user_id', 'movie_id'
```

Honestly, there is nothing wrong with your existing code.

The `name` property can be used in many `pandas` functions, e.g. sorting, grouping.